# set equal duration to images with ffmpeg python

Tags: python, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-python

Hi i want to make a video using images. Lets say i have an audio of 60 seconds and 6 images and i want my video to show images with equal durations i.e 10 second per image
but i couldn't figure it out how to do it
here is my code

```
import ffmpeg
input_audio = ffmpeg.input('./SARS/SARS.mp3')
input_still = ffmpeg.input('./SARS/*.jpg',t=20, pattern_type='glob', framerate=24)
(
    ffmpeg
    .concat(input_still, input_audio, v=1, a=1)
    .filter('scale', size='hd1080', force_original_aspect_ratio='increase')
    .output('./SARS/output.mp4')
    .run(overwrite_output=True)
)
```

any help is appriciated

Comment: `framerate` dictates how fast images are shown, so set it to be the reciprocal of the per-image duration: i.e., `framerate=0.1` in your case. Also, drop `t=20` as it'll limit the stream to only 2 images.

Comment: Also, I don't think `.concat` is what you need to use. You need to create separate audio and video streams and join them in forming the output object. I don't use `ffmpeg-python` package, but I can show you how to either as an ffmpeg cli command or using my `ffmpegio` package if you are interested.

Comment: Yes please tell me thanks, and what should i use t=? And what it means, i searched for it on google but couldn't find anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you can achieve this with `ffmpeg-python` but you can try one of the following:

**Plain CLI**

```
ffmpeg \
  -y \
  -i './SARS/SARS.mp3' \
  -pattern_type glob -framerate 0.1 -i './SARS/*.jpg' \
  -vf scale=size=hd1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=increase \
  './SARS/output.mp4'
```

You can run this in Python using `subprocess.run(['ffmpeg','-y',...])`

**[`ffmpegio`](https://github.com/python-ffmpegio/python-ffmpegio) Package**

For a one-time pure transcoding need, `ffmpegio` is actually an overkill and directly calling `ffmpeg` via `subprocess` is more than sufficient and faster, but if you do this kind of operations often you can give it a try.

```
pip install ffmpegio-core
```

```py
from ffmpegio.ffmpegprocess import run

run({'inputs': [
      ('./SARS/SARS.mp3', None)
      ('./SARS/*.jpg', {'pattern_type':'glob','framerate': 0.1})],
     'outputs': [
      ('./SARS/output.mp4', {'vf':'scale=size=hd1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=increase'})], 
    overwrite=True)
```

Essentially, it's like `subprocess` counterpart but takes a dict of parameters.

Comment: Wow thanks, i will try this first thing in the morning

Comment: hello dear it is saying vf is not defined

Comment: Sorry, it should be in quotes. I edited my post